# Yii2 название input'ов

Tags: php, yii2, mvc, yii, php7

Начинаю разбираться в `Yii2`, и не могу понять, возможно ли изменить стандартный формат наименования `input'ов`. Сейчас объясню подробнее.

В дефолтном шаблоне `Yii2`, на странице авторизации, поля `username` и `password` имеют следующие атрибуты `name`:

`LoginForm[username]` и `LoginForm[password]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, атрибут `name` генерируется по принципу `НазваниеМодели[НазваниеПоля]`.
Вопрос - можно ли как-нибудь скрыть название модели, и оставить только название поля в качестве атрибута?

То есть, чтобы в результате было как-то так:
`username` и `password`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.: на последнем скрине подправил исходный код элемента, для наглядности ^_^

Благодарю!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Нужно понимание зачем нужно избавление от этого. Так-то можно. Но зачем?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вообще вопрос задал больше из любопытства, дабы лучше понять работу Yii2. Однако, на вопрос "Зачем?" у меня есть пока что следующие аргументы: 1. поле "username" намного более практичнее, чем "LoginForm[username]". Особенно, если приходится отправлять форму вручную (через curl, например). Человеческому глазу намного приятнее такое представление, не так ли?) 2. На большинстве сайтов, в том числе и на StackOverflow, поля обозначены без лишних "префиксов" - например, поле, в котором я сейчас пишу, названо просто - `comment`, а не как-то вроде `PostComment['text']`. Спасибо!

Comment: Такая форма сделана специально. Так фреймворк производит валидацию. А также в контроллере достаточно прописать `$modal->validate()` для валидации полей модели. Для быстрой загрузки полей использовать `$model->load($_POST)`, в ином же случае, там будет много хлама. Т.е. это для внутренней работы фреймворка и для облегчения и автоматизирования работы с формой...то, что на SO и других сайтах так - ну ок. Пользователю абсолютно плевать на это. Верстальщик использует классы. Так что это никому совершенно не мешает. Через CURL это тоже не составляет труда т.к. это всего лишь ассоциативный массив

Comment: Так что если честно объективных причин не делать так - особо нет. Не хочется - тогда можно форму составлять не на основе ActiveForm А просто за счёт класса Helper в котором есть элементы для формы....либо совсем вручную составлять формы